# delete space in one line prints

Tags: python, printing, spaces

How to remove spaces in this print ?

For example

```
for i in range(5):
print i,
```

Will prints: 1 2 3 4 5

But I would like to get print like: 12345

Someone can help ?

Comment: Upgrade to 3.x and use the `end` parameter, and/or build the string you want *then* print it.

Comment: or do `sys.stdout.write(str(i))`

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, you can use:

```
for i in range(5):
    print(i, end="")
```

In Python 2, however you can not achieve it via simple print. There are two ways to do it:

```
# Way 1: Using "sys.stdout". But this will write to stdout 
>>> import sys
>>> for i in range(5):
...     sys.stdout.write(str(i))
... 
01234>>>

# Way 2: Convert it to list of string and then join them
>>> print ''.join(map(str, range(5)))
01234
```